# How to get the path of a selected file in input type="file" using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get the path of a selected file and store it in the database for future use.
I have the following code but it does not work.

```
$path = $_FILES['txtImage']['tmp_name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblquestions (q_category, q_question, q_image, q_correct, q_answer2, q_answer3, q_answer4) VALUES ('$_POST[txtCategory]','$_POST[txtQuestion]','$path','$_POST[txtCorrect]','$_POST[txtChoice2]','$_POST[txtChoice3]','$_POST[txtChoice4]')";
```

txtImage is the name of my input type="file" and $path is the code i am using but it does not work. IT just returns blank.

Anyone who can help me or lead me to a different, hopefully easier method? Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$tmp_path = $_FILES['txtImage']['tmp_name'];

$dest_path = path_where_in_your_server_you_want_this_image_to_be_moved.$_FILES['textImage']['name']; (eg: 'images/'.$_FILES['name'])

if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_path,$dest_path)){ //this will move the file from tmp   location in server to the destination you provide in the second parameter

$sql = "INSERT INTO tblquestions (q_category, q_question, q_image, q_correct, q_answer2,  q_answer3, q_answer4) VALUES ('$_POST[txtCategory]','$_POST[txtQuestion]','$dest_path','$_POST[txtCorrect]','$_POST[txtChoice2]','$_POST[txtChoice3]','$_POST[txtChoice4]')";

}else{

 echo "Image could not be uploaded"

}
```

Also keep in mind that there can be permission issues (with the directory that you want the image to be uploaded to)  while uploading the file.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 2):

PHP will store submitted files in a temporary directory, which you shouldn't be storing in the database as it'll be volatile.

Use PHP's `move_uploaded_file` function to move the file to where you'd like in your file system, and then store that path in your database.

Docs: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: I understand what you suggested. But i don't know how to edit my code. I'm new to php. Can you help me recreate my code? Any lead would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you set your form enctype correctly on the HTML side so that it is correctly able to work as it should.
Secondly, TMP is just a temporary location, you MUST move that file to a server readble directory using [PHP function move_uploaded_file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)
Read about enctypes, [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean) or [on w3 schools.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp)

```
<form name="YourForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
```